# own streaming source within home network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, audio, streaming

I'm looking for a way to create a streaming environment within my home network. I figured out DLNA or Airplay are probably the way to go but now I have a problem figuring out with which device I'm able to create a stream which is then consumed by different clients (speakers, ...) I know how to access files (especially music) through the network. I have a Synology NAS / Raspberry Pi / Home server ready to be configured. The stream producer should be running all the time (probably on the nas / homeserver) and the consumer should be able to consume the stream whenever they are turned on. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you taken a look at plex?

Comment: yes i took a look at plex, its kinda similar to the others, it only provides access to the music that is stored, im not able to stream music...

Comment: What source are you hoping to stream music from?  Your NAS?  Somewhere online?

Comment: preferably nas or home server, i figured out a way to stream but it just works for a single song, using vlc media player and then creating an http-stream which is then consumed through another vlc media player

Answer (score 0):

If you the streaming device eg: mobile / iPod is in a Bluetooth range then probably you can make use if NFC which should be available on all the latest devices or you can take advantage of UPnP technology.

take a look at the [article](http://lifehacker.com/5803975/what-is-upnp-and-how-do-i-use-it-to-stream-media-to-my-tv)

Let me know if you have any further questions regarding the same.

Comment: thanks for the response, but its the same problem as always, if i create a upnp-server, i can get access to my music/movie library but i want to create a stream that is always running (even when not used) so that when a receiving device is turned on it immediately is able to receive the stream (maybe stream is the wrong word?)